# Embed PDF to HTML object tag is hidden floating bar at the first time

Tags: html, object, pdf, iframe, embed

I have an issue about embed PDF link to HTML `<object>` tag.

[image]

The floating bar is like that.

- At first time the page loads, the floating bar is hidden even though I roll over this position.
- When I refresh page (press F5) then the floating bar is shown again.

I have tried `<iframe/>` `<embed/>` tags, however they can't solve this problem.

P/s: My customer don't allow to use PDF.js

Answer (score 0):

The option to disable/enable the read mode is controled by adobe and not by browser or html/js. Client have the option to change things how to view the document. Perpahs the correct way to enable/disable floating bar by doing this:

```
Quit your internet browser
Launch Acrobat (or Reader)
Choose Edit>Preferences
Click on the Internet category on the left
Deselect “Display in Read Mode by default”
Click the OK button.
Relaunch Acrobat
```

Something important to note, if you have both Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Reader, you need to do the above in both programs (same steps).